# Small model property for FOL sentence that has no free variables and no quantifiers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am trying to figure out if the statement in the title holds (couldn't find any reference to any similar question).

I.e. assume that I have a FOL sentence that is satisfiable by some model $M$, and the sentence has no free variables and no quantifiers. Can I claim that this sentence is also satisfiable by a finite model?

My intuition is it does, by defining a model that use the model $M$ and throwing from it every element in the domain that no instance in the sentence refers to, and then I need to fix the definition of the functions and relations in a correct manner, which I did not formalized yet.

I would like to hear your opinion on this statement and on my proof direction.

Comment: If you have only individual constants, the answer is obviously YES: replace each distinct atomic formula with a propositional letter and the formula will be a propositional one.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What do you mean by saying 'individual constants'? and the transform to propositional logic is good intuition, but how do I define a model (domain, interpretation to the functions and relations) by this transform?

Comment: You write "the sentence has no free variables and no quantifiers"; a *sentence* like that can be $c=c, f(c), P(c,d)$ and truth-functional combinations of similar atomic sentence. No other way...

Comment: If so, $c=c, f(c)$ etc. will be transformed to $P, Q$ and a compound formula like $c=c \to f(c)$ will be $P \to Q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Just to mention that there can be other relations except to equality, so a sentence like that can be: $R(c,f(f(c)))\land R(c,c)$. And maybe I miss something, but the transformation you does not imply a model, and what I'm after is a finite model that satisfies the original sentence. (thank for your answers btw)

Comment: To elaborate, I am looking after finite model like the one we can show there is for a satisfiable formula in monadic logic, or in EPR logic

Comment: You can see the general procedure for FOL formulas into S.C. Kleene, [ML (1967)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Mathematical_Logic), page 86; you have only to simplify it taking into account that you have no free/bound variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133119/discussion-between-e-ad-and-mauro-allegranza).